# onclick load function in php

Tags: javascript, php, function

I m have 2 my code and one work and when i use code 2 not work.

Javascript is still the same. 
This is javascript and work

```
function addto(selid)
{
    var i;
    var item = "";

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
        item = "incart_"+i; 
        if(getCookie(item) == "")
            {  
            setCookie(item,selid,24);  
                break;
            }
    }
```

}

This code work

```html
    <button onclick='addto("1");' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart shop-card-icon"> </i></button >
```

but when i use php  does not respond

// If i use the action in php it goes.

```
<button  <?php echo "onclick='addto('".$row["id"]. "');'"; ?>  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart shop-card-icon"> </i></button>
```

Comment: Can you please share PHP code as well?

Comment: You are using the same quote twice. You need to use double quote for the `onclick` attribute's encapsulation, but escape it so it doesn't close the PHP encapsulation. e.g. `echo "onclick=\"addto('`

Comment: your quotes are all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP only on the dynamic part:

```
<button onclick="addto('<?= $row['id'] ?>')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart shop-card-icon"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an escaping issue, you can either echo the whole button and use proper escaping on the quotes, or just echo the dynamic part

Echo just the dynamic part (best option)

```
<button  onclick="addto('<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart shop-card-icon"> </i></button>
```

Echo the whole button

```
<?php echo '<button onclick="addto(\''. $row["id"] .'\')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart shop-card-icon"> </i></button>'; ?>
```